# Does the series 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.09, 0.08... diverge to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If one has a sequence 0.5+0.4+0.3+0.2+0.1+0.09+0.08+0.07+0.06+0.05... and this series continues to infinity, does the sum of this series reach infinity? If so why? If not why not?

So far I have been able to reduce to problem to 1.5 for summing all the 1/10 + 0.55 for summing all the 1/100 place values, 0.055 for summing all the 1/1000 place values etc.

As such you get 1.5+0.55+0.055+0.0055....

(the background reason for asking this question is related to summing reciprocals of prime numbers).

Comment: There is some guesswork involved in interpreting your "series", but it appears to be easily rewritten as a geometric series with common ratio one tenth.  So it converges.

Comment: This basically is the sum of the series (plural) $k \sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left(\dfrac{1}{10^n}\right)$, where $k\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that:
$$0.55 + 0.055 + 0.0055 + \dots = 0.55\cdot \sum_{k=0}^\infty 10^{-k} = 0.55\cdot\frac {1}{1- \frac1{10}} \approx 0.61$$

Answer (score 4):

This series is convergent - you have $1.5+0.55+0.055+0.0055+...=1.5+0.55\cdot(1+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10^2}+\frac{1}{10^3}+...=1.5+0.55\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}}$ (last equality is the formula for the sum of geometric series).