# Does this series of approximations of reciprocals of prime numbers diverge or converge?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Research done:
There are 4 prime numbers between 0 and 10. This means there are 4 primes whose reciprocals are > 0.1. The exact sum of these prime numbers = $\frac{247}{210}$ $\approx 1.176$

There are 21 prime numbers between 10 and $10^2$. This means there are 21 prime numbers whose reciprocals are  between $10^{-1}$ and $10^{-2}$ The sum of the reciprocals of these prime numbers is $\approx 0.6266$
There are 143 primes between $10^2$ and $10^3$. This means that there are 143 primes whose reciprocals are between $10^{-2}$ and $10^{-3}$.The sum of the reciprocals of these prime numbers is $\approx \frac{143}{525}$ $\approx 0.2724$
There are 1061 primes between $10^3$ and $10^4$. This means that there are 1061 primes whose reciprocals are between $10^{-3}$ and $10^{-4}$. The sum of the reciprocals of these primes is $\approx \frac{1061}{5335} \approx 0.19888$
There are 8363 primes between $10^4$ and $10^5$. This means that there are 8363 primes whose reciprocals are between $10^{-4}$ and $10^{-5}$. The sum of the reciprocals of these primes is $\approx \frac{8363}{53648} \approx 0.155886$
There are 68906 primes between $10^5$ and $10^6$. This means that there are 68906 primes whose reciprocals are between $10^{-5}$ and $10^{-6}$. The sum of the reciprocals of these primes $\approx \frac{68906}{538357} \approx 0.12799$.
There are 586081 primes between $10^6$ and $10^7$. This means that there are 586081 primes whose reciprocals are between $10^{-6}$ and $10^{-7}$. The sum of the reciprocals of these primes $\approx \frac{586081}{5401599} \approx 0.1085$.

(The calculations have been done with a high accuracy only not completely shown)

**Question**:
As we can clearly see the increase of the sum diminishes as prime numbers get higher and higher. However, this still remains to be proved for all primes. However if this would be true: you would get the sum of the series: 1.176+0.6266+0.2724+0.19888+0.155886+0.12799+0.1085... where the values keep getting lower. Does such a series necessarily diverge to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, diverges, proved by Euler in early 18th century:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Comment: I know Euler's proof. He arrives at it from a very different angle. The question at hand is: if you have the sum of a series of numbers which diminishes do you get a divergent series? This might be a different question than Euler posed. 
Please also check: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492372/does-the-series-0-5-0-4-0-3-0-2-0-1-0-09-0-08-diverge-to-infinity

Comment: (You must acknowledge that it is a bit weird that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes to 10 million equals $\approx$ 2.666556 and less and less will be added when you take prime numbers between 10 million and 100 million, and 100 million and 1 billion.)

Comment: "if you have the sum of a series of numbers which diminishes do you get a divergent series?" What does this mean? For any *convergent* sum $\sum a_n$, it must be true that $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: @St. Clair Bij: You choose a very very specific delimiters for grouping  - if you want the series to be convergent, diminishing of  partial sums should occur for any grouping method you can imagine.

Comment: @z100 I agree. I think that if you would take the group sample larger than I have it will also be the case. It is useful to take a large enough groups to take into account the fact that prime numbers are not equally distributed. Larger groups would only make it easier to see that the partial sums would diminish.

Comment: I think that the partial sums will be fluctuating for smaller groups. This is because it might be that some primes are clustered closer to each other.

Comment: @z100 to the bigger picture however if I could show that the partial sums would diminish, would that mean that the series is convergent or divergent?

Comment: maybe it is possible to construct group delimiters based on the  idea as Paul Erdos's proof by contradiction (see in upper link)

Comment: @z100 suppose for a second the issue of grouping could be ignored (I will still need to adress it later) Would this type of series be of a different kind than this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492372/does-the-series-0-5-0-4-0-3-0-2-0-1-0-09-0-08-diverge-to-infinity?noredirect=1#comment3039891_1492372 (except that i do not actually know the next term in the sequence just that it is smaller than the previous one.)